# Unable to display images after uploading them in react component

Tags: reactjs

I want to upload multiples images then display them in browser. I wrote this code mentioned by this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/x33qy5kqxp).
I got the name of images displayed in place of images:

```
Image1.png
Image2.png
```

How can I fix that and if someone knows another npm module which upload and display images as a gallery I will be grateful if mentioned it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the property `withPreview` to the `<ImageUploader />` gives you a preview of all "uploaded" images.

```
const UploadImage = props => {
  const { onDrop } = props;
  return (
    <ImageUploader
      withIcon
      buttonText="Upload Image"
      onChange={onDrop}
      imgExtension={[".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".gif"]}
      maxFileSize={5242880}
      withPreview
    />
  );
};
```

You can see this change implemented [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5zvjm5803l).

This library looks like it can achieve what you want right out the box. [See the documentation for the library for more details.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload)